# How to plot millions of points in web maps with python, postgis, leaflet, and etc.?

Tags: python, postgis, raster, gdal, leaflet

I am building a web map for plotting millions and billions of point data. It seems impossible because millions of point data might blow the memory and browser. I am wondering whether it is possible to plot that much data on a web map using for example leaflet or google earth engine.

My idea right now is convert all of these data into a raster image, so the plotting might become possible. But I have two questions here, how to convert the point data into raster, and whether it is still possible to do gis with the point data?

If there are other ways to plot the points (probably point cloud?), please provide me some clues. I am totally stuck right now.

Comment: This question is rather broad. What do you mean with "do gis"? What are your requirements? Rendering raster maps from points would be rather straight-forward.

Answer (score 3):

A great place to start would be to checkout [datashader](https://github.com/bokeh/datashader)

It is a bin-based rasterization pipeline written in Python which can aggregate billions of 2d points.

Read the Docs: http://datashader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Wow! this it just amazing! I heard about this but never knew it can rasterize billions of 2d points.